# Chat app EditText section will not render/hidden from design preview

Tags: android

I can't see my EditText section in the design preview, nor in my app. The hint and everything seem to not render. Here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="340dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:fabSize="mini" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Message..." />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="16dp"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can see my send button and everything else. I can't seem to spot the issue. This is straight out of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xn0tQHpMDnM

Comment: remove `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginStart` from `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: It's visible now. All solved! Clicking randomly in the design section is very bad.

Comment: @V-rundPuro-hit please post your comment as an answer to close the question

Answer (score 0):

remove `layout_marginLeft` and `layout_marginStart` from `FloatingActionButton`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:tint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
```

Answer (score -1):

In your layout you're requiring the TextInputLayout to be aligned to the left of the Flaoting Action Button, and then to the start of it. These two rules make the TextInputLayout to start just before the FAB, and to finish just before the FAB. It'll result in having the TextInputLayout with a 0dp width.

To solve the issue, this code

```
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fab"
```

should be modified. Just delete the layout_toStartOf rule.